# Having left and right content boxes css

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I have an html document and a css file with it. Here is what the code section I am working on looks like:

```
<div class="contentcenter">
    <div class="contentleft">
        <h1>Left</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi ...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentright">
        <h1>Right</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a picture that is 1000px wide centered above these elements, and I want the left element to align in the center of the page such that it begins at the left-most edge of the picture towards the middle, have a gap, and then have the right element display and reach to the right-most border of the picture. e.g.

```
|--------------Picture--------------------------|
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|-----------------------------------------------|

|--left--------------|    |-------right---------|
|                    |    |                     |
|                    |    |                     |
|                    |    |                     |
|                    |    |                     |
|--------------------|    |---------------------|
```

All of this, would be centered in the page. Here is my css, but it doesn't give me the result I am looking for.

```
.contentcenter
{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width=1000px;
    border:3px solid red;
}
.contentleft,
.contentright
{
    position:inherit;
    float:left;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width:auto;
    max-width:450px;
    border:3px solid #00CD00;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial, Times, serif;
}
.contentleft h1,
.contentright h1
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:white;
    font-family:Arial;
    display:block;
    background-color:#00CD00;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of know your problem, apart from having the left and right boxes begin from left and right. you want the entire content to be centered as well

My solution goes here : http://jsfiddle.net/rvjd7/

Before we begin explaining the code:

1. width=1000px does not make sense in css. it should be width:1000px (with a colon)
2. your html is the same
3. Here is your css: notice that one box is floated to the left while the other one is floated to the right. `contentcenter` however is given overflow:auto so that it can contain the two floated children `contentleft` and `contentright`.

.picture{
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
}

```
.contentcenter
{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
width:1000px;
background-color:lightgrey;
overflow:auto;
}
.contentleft,
.contentright
{
position:inherit;
float:left;
margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
width:auto;
max-width:450px;
border:3px solid #00CD00;
padding:0;
font-family:Arial, Times, serif;
}
.contentright
{
position:inherit;
float:right;
margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
width:auto;
max-width:450px;
border:3px solid #00CD00;
padding:0;
font-family:Arial, Times, serif;
}
.contentleft h1,
.contentright h1
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:white;
font-family:Arial;
display:block;
background-color:#00CD00;
padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight modification of your code to give what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
.contentcenter
{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
width:1000px;
border:3px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
}

.contentleft {float: left;}

.contentright {float: right;}

.contentleft, .contentright
{
width:450px;
border:3px solid #00CD00;
padding:0;
font-family:Arial, Times, serif;
}

.contentleft h1, .contentright h1
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:white;
font-family:Arial;
display:block;
background-color:#00CD00;
padding: 5px 0;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="contentcenter">
    <div class="contentleft">
        <h1>Left</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi ...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentright">
        <h1>Right</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi ...</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

One major typo you had was `width=1000px;`, which should be `width: 1000px;`. Other than that, the most important thing is to float the boxes in different directions.

Here's an example with a div that imitates the image that you mentionsed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
.contentcenter
{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
width:1000px;
border:3px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
}

.contentleft {float: left;}

.contentright {float: right;}

.contentleft, .contentright
{
width:450px;
border:3px solid #00CD00;
padding:0;
font-family:Arial, Times, serif;
}

.contentleft h1, .contentright h1
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:white;
font-family:Arial;
display:block;
background-color:#00CD00;
padding: 5px 0;
}

.img {height: 200px; background: #e7e7e7; margin-bottom: 30px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="contentcenter">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="contentleft">
        <h1>Left</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi ...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contentright">
        <h1>Right</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi ...</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close: make sure to `float:right` on the right-hand div. I'd recommend wrapping it all in a container div as well so you can set a width once and have it all fit. Here's a bare-bones example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="imgHold">
        <img src="[ ... ]" />
    </div>
    <div class="contentcenter">
        <div class="contentleft">
            [ ... ]
        </div>

        <div class="contentright">
            [ ... ]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
    width:1000px;
}
.contentleft,
.contentright{
    float:left;
    width:49%; /* set this to any value you need */
}
.contentright{
    float:right;
    /* You could add width here again if you want them different widths */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/faVRa/